# Project euler 8 in C

Tags: c

Find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the `1000-digit number`.

> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
>   96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
>   85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
>   12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
>   66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
>   62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
>   30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
>   70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
>   65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
>   52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
>   53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
>   83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
>   82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
>   16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
>   17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
>   24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
>   07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
>   84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
>   05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
>   71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

I have 2 question regarding this problem.

1. How do I store this number?
2. How do I access individual digits?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @eaj - I'm guessing it's more of a puzzle than homework, given the Project Euler reference.

Comment: what is homework here? why should I tag this as homework?

Comment: Never mind, I missed the project euler reference. Carry on.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get it into an array of integers, this will probably make the problem easiest.

Then your `get_prod_of_five_consec_digits(start_index, array_of_ints)` function will be able to have a reasonable signature and give better code separation.

Comment: Forget an array of integers. Buffer 5 characters and subtract `'0'` from incoming.

Answer (score 3):

Store it as a string.  Access the digits as characters by index.

Answer (score 2):

The big integer multiplication problem. You can save the integer as char literal with an array. For example, 123 we have `char a[]={1, 2, 3}`. Then you can access each digit with array index.

Comment: should I put comma after every digit? It's a 1000 digit number.

Comment: @AmitTiwari I think the original problem want you to find the five consecutive integer whose product is not exceeding 1000 digits. Then you need not encode the resulting 1000-digit number. What you need to do is find the five number whose digit is quite limited.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with big integer multiplication.

Comment: @Atom any more elegant solution?

Comment: @Summer_More_More_Tea I was referring only to your 1st sentence, the subsequent sentences seem OK. The solution proposed by myself seems faster to type into the computer than typing "char a[]={7,3,1,...}".

Comment: @Atom maybe I mistake the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to store it anywhere in your program. Copy the number into a file, remove all newlines. In the program, use `getchar()` 1000 times (or until EOF) to read the next digit from the standard input. Use shell redirection to feed the file into the program.

```
./euler8 < euler8.txt
```

Comment: that's a good idea too.. but we can do it the other way round using char *. I do not have good knowledge on using files as inputs and other related things. It would be nice if you could point me to some reference regarding the file I/O.

Answer (score 1):

I think, better to write this number in file, next use `fgets` function (copy one string from file in new buff string) make a solution

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number in a character array/String variable. Manipulating the resulting string and performing arithmetic operations on it is left to you.
Its a good idea to create a class (/datatype) to deal with such big numbers later on. [Here is a sample class created by ACRush](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard/do?cmd=GetSourceCode&contest=311101&problem=322102&io_set_id=1&username=ACRush).

Comment: Why do you need a big number class for this?  As I understand the problem the largest possible number is 9^5 which fits easily into an int.

Comment: There is no need to use big integers.

Comment: "How do I store this number? How do I access individual digits?" was what he asked. Hence the answer.
But yes, the solution to this particular problem will not need the use of big-integers.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++

You can store as a string, like:

```
char arr[] = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
             "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
             "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
             "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
             "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
             "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
             "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
             "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
             "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
             "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
             "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
             "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
             "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
             "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
             "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
             "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
             "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
             "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
             "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
             "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
```

Here, we can also write this string in one line but that cover alot horizontal space

And access as

```
      arr[0] - '0' => 7,
      arr[1] - '0' => 3,...
```

Here we subtract '0' from array just to convert it into int.

link:[Why does subtracting '0' in C result in the number that the char is representing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598698/why-does-subtracting-0-in-c-result-in-the-number-that-the-char-is-representing)

Comment: @Khageshwar Hi! Please format the code part properly