# Why does subtracting '0' in C result in the number that the char is representing?

Tags: c++, c, digits

Can someone explain why this works?

```
char c = '9';
int x = (int)(c - '0');
```

Why does subtracting '0' from an ascii code of a char result the number that that char is representing?

Comment: This is a good question. Do not be distracted by all the answers that use the ASCII table as an explanation for the observed behaviour though.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Because the char are all represented by a number and '0' is the first of them all.

**On the table below you see that:**

```
'0' => 48
'1' => 49


'9' => 57.
```

**As a result:** (`'9'` - `'0'`) = (57 − 48) = 9

[image]
*Source: http://www.asciitable.com*

Comment: On [the machine I work on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout) we have `'0' => 240`, but `'9'` - `'0'` is still 9.

Comment: +1. (EBCDIC is kind of peculiar), but you are right. That's why `'9' - '0'` is the right thing to do and `'9' - 48` should be avoided. On can always expect the characters 0 to 9 to be set in ascending order, but their actual value may differ.

Comment: This assumes an ASCII encoding is in use.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - no it doesn't. It assumes that whichever  encoding is used has the values 0 through 9 internal representation stored consecutively (and in ascending order). Their absolute values are irrelevant, their sequential-ness is all that matters. And good luck finding a relevant char set that doesn't store them sequentially.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - see 'C Programming language by K&R' Chapter 1. I believe the author was one of the collaborators that's authored C.

Comment: @AaronHS: You're correct about the digits (which are required to be stored consecutively and in ascending order as you say). I assume I was referring to the prominent use of an ASCII table to prove it - a standard quote about that requirements on digit representations would be more appropriate.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - fair enough

Comment: This is the right answer for the wrong reason.  ISO C does *not* guarantee that the source or execution character set is ASCII or Unicode.  It does guarantee this fact about decimal *digits*, but *not* about alphabetic characters.  This answer incorrectly implies that you could follow the same reasoning and assume that `'a' + 6 == 'f'` in an int->hex function, but that's not 100% portable to C implementations that don't use ASCII/Unicode.  (Which almost nobody cares about in practice, but still.)

Answer (score 31):

`char` is an integer type, just like `int` and family. An object of type `char` has some numerical value. The mapping between characters that you type in a character literal (like `'0'`) and the value that the `char` object has is determined by the encoding of that character in the *execution character set*:

- C++11 §2.14.3:

  > An ordinary character literal that contains a single *c-char* representable in the execution character set has type `char`, with value equal to the numerical value of the encoding of the *c-char* in the execution character set.
- C99 §6.4.4.4:

  > An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > An integer character constant has type `int`.

  Note that the `int` can be converted to a `char`.

The choice of execution character set is up to the implementation. More often than not, the choice is ASCII compatible, so the tables posted in other answers have the appropriate values. However, the character set does not *need* to be ASCII compatible. There are some restrictions, though. One of them is as follows (C++11 §2.3, C99 §5.2.1):

> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
> _ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than the value of the previous.

This means that whatever value the character `'0'` has, the character `'1'` has value one more than `'0'`, and character `'2'` has value one more than that, and so on. The numeric characters have consecutive values. You can summarise the mapping like so:

```
Character:            0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
Corresponding value:  X    X+1  X+2  X+3  X+4  X+5  X+6  X+7  X+8  X+9
```

All of the digit characters have values offset from the value of `'0'`.

That means, if you have a character, let's say `'9'` and subtract `'0'` from it, you get the "distance" between the value of `'9'` and the value of `'0'` in the execution character set. Since they are consecutive, the distance will be 9.

Comment: In C, an ordinary character literal ... has type `int`.

Comment: @pmg I hadn't noticed that the question was tagged [tag:c] as well. I'll add the differences in.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's *not* guaranteed that `'a' .. 'z'` are contiguous, and in fact they're not in EBCDIC.  (They are in ASCII / Unicode).  You quoted a list that started with the alphabet, but the key phrase is "each character *after 0*", and that list put the alphabet first.

Answer (score 23):

Because the C standard guarantees that the characters `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9` are always in this order regarding their numerical character code. So, if you subtract the char code of `'0'` from another digit, it will give its position relative to `0`, which is its value...

From the C standard, Section 5.2.1 Character sets:

> In both the source and execution basic character sets, the
>   value of each character after 0 in the above list of decimal digits shall be one greater than
>   the value of the previous

Comment: +1, but it would be nice to add the number of the section of the standard where this is specified.

Answer (score 7):

Because, the literals are arranged in sequence.

So if `0` was 48, `1` will be 49, `2` will be 50 etc.. in ASCII, then `x` would contain, ascii value of `'9'` minus the ascii value of `'0'` which means, ascii value of `'9'` would be 57 and hence, `x` would contain `57 - 48 = 9`.

Also, `char` is an integral type.

Comment: yes, you are right, it makes sense now, thanks! (this was not a very smart question ;D)

Comment: This doesn't depend on the locale being ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

the code ascii of numeric chars are ordered in the order `'0' '1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9'` as indicated in the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

so if we make difference beween asii of `'9'` and ascii of `'0'` we will get `9`

Answer (score 3):

In the ASCII-table the Digits are aligned sequentially, starting with the lowest code for `0`. If you subtract a higher number from `0`, you create the difference of the two ASCII-values.
So, `9` has value `57` and `0` has `48`, so if you subtract 48 from 57 you get 9.
Just have a look at the ASCII-table.

Look [here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [ASCII TABLE](http://www.asciitable.com/):

```
'9' in ASCII =  57 //in Decimal

'0' in ASCII =  48 //in Decimal
```

## **57 - 48 = 9**

Comment: I believe it would be same because '0'-'9' are ordered in increasing order. Because even if it's in [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-u-cyr/table4.jpg). '0' - '9' are also ordered in increasing order.

Comment: Right, that is the question. Somewhere there is a rule that says that the numbers must be in increasing sequence, and the ASCII table follows this rule. So this behaviour is guaranteed to apply with other encodings. But just quoting the ASCII table is no explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll make sure that I will an explanation next time. ;)

Answer (score -1):

First, try:

```
cout << (int)'0' << endl;
```

now try:

```
cout << (int)'9' << endl;
```

the charictors represent numbers in text form, but have a different value in when taken as a number.
Windows uses a Number to decide which charictor to print. So the number 0x30 represents the charictor 0 in the windows OS. The number 0x39 represents the charictor 9. After all, all a computer can recognize is numbers, it does'nt know what a "char" is.

Unfortunatly `(int)('f' - '0')` does not equal 15, though.

This gives you the various charictors and the number windows uses to represent them.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx

If you need to find that for another OS, you can search: `Virtual Key Codes <OSname>` in Google. to see what other OS's have as their codes.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows (or any other OS, such as the one where C was created).  The contiguous encoding of the digit characters is required by the C standard, and can be relied upon on any conformant system.