# Is C++ ASCII-aware?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

A colleague told me:

> C++ is not ASCII-aware.

The *source character set* of a C++ program is implementation-defined, so to what extent is my colleague incorrect?

Comment: You should ask your colleague what he meant by that.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: .... dammit. Gonna need more SO accounts. Start a stage show up in this joint.

Comment: As a strawman, maybe in the sense that the characters for the digits 0-9 must be in that order, without any gaps? This has nothing much to do with ascii per se, but it would disallow some contrived encodings...

Comment: @PlasmaHH is there a IANA-registered encoding that would not be allowed by that?

Comment: Just a comment: `int ⓽ = 9;` is valid C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The c++ compiler needs to be ASCII aware when it links the numeric `48` value to `'0'`. So yes, it needs to be ASCII-aware.

But does it always needs to? Imagine you work with [EBCDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Codepage_layout) (`'0' => 240`). Then the compiler probably doesn't care about ASCII. Maybe that's what you colleague meant.

C++, generally speaking, does not really care about ASCII. It is an implementation detail.

Comment: [This was discussed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598698/subtracting-0/15598711#15598711) some time ago. [Bo Persson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson) said: `On the machine I work on we have '0' => 240, but '9' - '0' is still 9`

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard text is "aware" of ASCII in that it makes non-normative mention in a footnote:

> `[C++11: Footnote 14]:` The glyphs for the members of the basic source character set are intended to identify characters from the subset of ISO/IEC 10646 which corresponds to the ASCII character set. However, because the mapping from source file characters to the source character set (described in translation phase 1) is specified as implementation-defined, an implementation is required to document how the basic source characters are represented in source files.

In doing so, it is declaring that the standardised language itself is *not* ASCII-aware.

*"Seems like awareness of ASCII to me!"* you might say. Well, no. The mere mention of "ASCII" in the language definition has not made the *language* ASCII-aware. This is in the same way that you can program a robot to say the words "I am not self-aware" without requiring that the robot become aware of self.

Comment: inb4 you can program robot to say words.

Comment: can you tell me some examples  languages  those are not-ascii aware.  are  low-level assembly? binary ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: C++ is one.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok now I understood. :) after reading again.

Comment: maybe he meant the previous one. Just sayin'

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Interesting! As a superset, is that by definition, or merely by design/through intent?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: By definition I guess - it defines the code points 0-127 to be the same as their ASCII equivalents. (Sorry, I just accidentally deleted my comment; I'll retype it in a second)

Comment: However, the definition of a `universal-character-name` is based on the Universal Character Set (ISO/IEC 10646), which is a superset of ASCII. So the language does have some awareness of ASCII.