# atoi function in ctype library not working in C

Tags: c, atoi

I almost read all of the articles about my problem in stackoverflow but they didn't solve it. I want a program that sums all the numbers in a string and shows me result. For example, when I write "a2s23l", it shows me 2 + 2 + 3 = 7 on screen. I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    char input[15];
    printf("Write smth: ");
    gets(input);

    int i, result = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=15; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(input[i]) != 0)
        {
            result = result + atoi(input[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("Your result: %d", result);

    return 0;
}
```

this is not working. I think there's something wrong about atoi function. Can you guys help me about this?

Comment: The argument to `atoi` must be a string, not a `char`.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning when you tried to compile `atoi(input[i])`

Comment: Never describe a problem as “not working.” Always state what you observe and what you desire instead, as well as any input and conditions needed to reproduce the problem. E.g., say “When I try to compile this, my compiler prints the error message *text of error message*” or “This program compiles with a warning I ignored, but when it runs, it prints *exact text of output*, but I want it to print *exact desired text*.”

Comment: You don't need to use `atoi()` to convert a single digit to a number. Just use `input[i] - '0'`

Comment: @EricPostpischil i will pay attention next time, thank you.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I understand that why atoi function didn't worked, but I don't understand why 'input[i] - '0'' is worked.

Comment: Because all the numeric character codes are sequential.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15598698/why-does-subtracting-0-in-c-result-in-the-number-that-the-char-is-representing

Comment: @Barmar okay, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`atoi(input[i])` is a problem as `int atoi(const char *)` expects a `const char *` and `input[i]` is a `char`.

This implies OP did not have all compiler warnings enabled.
Save time, enable all compiler warnings.

Since `input[i]` is a digit character, to convert to a digit value:

```
int single_digit_value = input[i] - '0';
result = result + single_digit_value;
```

---

Overrun

`for(i=0; i<=15; i++)` may iterate past the end of the string.  Instead look for the *null character*.

```
// for(i=0; i<=15; i++)
for(i=0; input[i]; i++)
```

---

**Evil `gets()`**

[Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359).

Comment: Thank you very much.